# Can I run 2 workers doing different tasks to one and other on gunicorn heroku

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn

I am trying to run 2 files test.py and test2.py using gunicorn and heroku, I want to be able to put them both on one node as separate workers from my procfile but I have no idea how. I have tried this:

```
worker: gunicorn test.py --timeout 3600 --workers 1 --log-file -
worker2: gunicorn test2.py --timeout 3600 --workers 1 --log-file -
```

and

```
worker: gunicorn test.py --timeout 3600 --workers 1 --log-file -
worker: gunicorn test2.py --timeout 3600 --workers 1 --log-file -
```

sorry if this is a bad question but I would really like some help.

Edit: one of them runs but the other does not, both run if they are the only one trying to run.

Edit 2: worked it out! Answer in comments

Comment: i worked it out, I forgot to scale dynos i used `cd MyApp` and `heroku ps:scale worker2=1 worker=1` with the first section of code as the procfile

Comment: What kind of web server are you running when you don't require a `PORT`? Only a `web` process can bind to `PORT` and you can only have one `web` process. You are not using a `web` process you are using `worker`. And gunicorn is something you use when serving a web server which requires a `PORT`.

Comment: two discord bots

Comment: Why do you need gunicorn?

Comment: No idea but it works exactly how I want it to